# Validation error message for each textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have here is validation for comparing textbox values. I have quantity textbox and a hidden textbox, If quantity textbox is lower than the hidden textbox error message will display in span. But the problem is even in other span that has a correct value error message always appears.

Just like the picture below if quantity is less than the hidden textbox error message display but on the other textbox which is has a correct value error message is still display. Help?

[image]

```
$('.n_quantity,.pr_total').each(function () {
    var textBox1 = $(".n_quantity");
    var textBox2 = $(".pr_total");
    for (var i = 0, len = textBox1.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (parseInt(textBox2[i].value) > parseInt(textBox1[i].value)) {
            $(this).next("span.val_over").html("Over").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
<p>
    <label for="">PR Quantity</label>
    <input name="n_quantity[]" id="n_quantity" class="qty tb1 n_quantity" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['total_quantity'] ?>" />
    <span class="val_qty val_over"></span>
</p>
<p style="display:none;">
    <input id="pr_total" class="tb2 pr_total" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['total_quantity'];?>" readonly="readonly">
</p>
```

Comment: Why use `.each()` and then pull out the same lists again and iterate with a `for` loop?

Comment: You're iterating way too many times, and you need to select the `.val_over` element relative to the input that failed validation. But we need to see your html to give you a complete answer.

Comment: One way to solve it is to iterate over containers that contain pairs, and then inside the function pull out each item of the pair to compare.  jQuery has powerful enough selectors to do it but `$(selector1,selector2)` isn't it.

Comment: @paul I used for loop bcoz of multiple editing records. What should I do?

Comment: See, perhaps, `$.find()` http://api.jquery.com/find/ -- If each input/hidden pair were in a div, you could use `.each` to iterate over those divs and then use `$.find()` in the iteration function to find the input and hidden elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the editable fields, then traverse the dom to the related elements:

```
$('.n_quantity').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $total = $this.closest('p').next().find('.pr_total');

    if (parseInt($this.val(), 10) > parseInt($total.val(), 10)) {
        $this.siblings('.val_over').html('Over').addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    }    
});
```

Comment: I want to ask why there's 10 ?

Comment: That's the radix. Specifying 10 means you want it parsed as base 10, or decimal. Here's more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt